# Make project происходит без ошибок, но при build apk Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateConfigSigning'. > Keystore file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Полная ошибка: C:\Users\1\Desktop***\app\Users\user\Desktop\ProjectEP.jks not found for signing config 'config'.
Исходники проекта: https://github.com/EuphoriaDev/Euphoria-VK-Client

Comment: покажите gradle

Comment: кейстор файл не теряли?

Comment: какой именно gradle?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Исходники проекта: https://github.com/EuphoriaDev/Euphoria-VK-Client

Answer (score 1):

Как ответил сам разработчик, нужно использовать debug режим сборки. 
И получилось!

Answer (score 0):

У вас явная ошибка в пути до кейстора

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '*****'
            storeFile file('/Users/user/Desktop/ProjectEP.jks')  //укажите правильный путь до файла подписи приложения
            storePassword '*******'
        }
    }
```